# Restore mysql backup via crontab not working

Tags: mysql, shell, cron, debian, redmine

Good afternoon, I want to automate redundancy for Redmine. I have created a second server, which is waiting for the first one to crash, while updating its database. However, at the moment of updating the database is a strange problem, I'll try to describe it.

Running the script manually from the console, the database is copied and updated without any problems, but as soon as I call the same script from crontab database is only downloaded but no restores.

Maybe there is some special way to restore the database via crontab?

OS: Debian 11

The redmine build by bitnami

Here is the script code itself

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -f -L3310:localhost:3306 bitnami@192.168.100.108 -N
MYSQL_PWD=******** mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -P 3310 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --databases bitnami_redmine --add-drop-database > /home/bitnami/backups/db_backups/redmine_db_mon_1.sql

sleep 5
killall ssh

sleep 2
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop apache

sleep 2
MYSQL_PWD=******** mysql -u root < /home/bitnami/backups/db_backups/redmine_db_mon_1.sql

sleep 2
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
```

Comment: _This may be a silly question_ But if the first server is Crashed, how are you going to copy the database from it?

Comment: As soon as the first server goes down, the flow is redirected to the second. Copying is performed so that the data will be +- actual during the recovery of the primary server

Comment: But if the First - Crashed server contains the database you are copying FROM ..... There will be no database there as the server is crashed and cannot be accessed. And if your data is unimportant enough for a recovery to be `+- actual` then why bother with a automatic fail over mechanism

Comment: Maybe a read of [This Document - Replication and auto-failover made easy with MySQL Utilities](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/replication-and-auto-failover-made-easy-with-mysql-utilities) may help shape your mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am too lazy to understand and configure replication, synchronization and other things, made a simple script.

So, to make it work I had to add sudo to Mysql, which is strange.
But it's like this

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p***** < /home/bitnami/backups/db_backups/redmine_db_mon_1.sql
```